# How can i display extra text for android share extension using webintent plugin in ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using webintent plugin for android Extension.
when i open my browser and click  share  my extension will display.

My Extension is showing properly.

Now, i want when i click my extension i want to list some categories name.

Any idea how to do this ?

Here is my AndroidManifest file code:-

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.ionicframework.myappDevelopment1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="MainActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Here is mu app.js code:-

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'starter.controllers', 'ngStorage', 'toaster','angular.filter','angular-loading-bar','ngTagsInput'])
  .run(function($ionicPlatform, userInfo) {

 $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
 if (window.plugins && window.plugins.webintent) {
        window.plugins.webintent.getExtra(window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_TEXT, function (url) {
               userInfo.getCategory().then(function(result) {
                                var html = [];
                result.forEach(function(category) {
                                    html.push(category.category_name);
                                  });
                                  document.querySelector("#categoryList").innerHTML = html;
                                   },function(err){
                               alert(err);
                        });  
        }, function() { //Fail
              alert ("error");          
            });
      }  

    });
  })
```

Here is my index.html file:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

</head>

<body ng-app="starter">
<ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right" class="slide-left-right">
    </ion-nav-view>

  <toaster-container toaster-options="{'time-out': 3000}"></toaster-container>
  <div id="categoryList"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
 if (window.plugins && window.plugins.webintent) {
        window.plugins.webintent.getExtra(window.plugins.webintent.EXTRA_TEXT, function (url) {
              $ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('./templates/categorylist.html', {
                                           scope: $rootScope,
                                           }).then(function(popover) {
                                                   $rootScope.popover = popover;
                                                     //get result by calling factory etc 
                                                     $rootScope.categories = result;  

                                                 $rootScope.popover.show();
                                                   });
        }, function() { //Fail
              alert ("error");          
            });
      }
```